Minus operator not fast enough for comparison over DB link
I have a table in oracle, which I need to compare and check the results using minus operation.
My Query is like below.
select 
col1, col2, col3 etc.
from Tab1@db_link
minus
select 
col1, col2, col3 etc.
from Tab1;

I need to know, how this works like whether all the data is pulled into the oracle server while it runs or record wise comparison happens ?
My current version of oracle on both DB is 19c.
I tried, but i could not understand how it internally works in Oracle. I am familiar with the function, but need more inputs on Oracle's internal working.

You would need to look at the query plan.  But realistically either all the data from the local table will be sent to the remote database to do the minus or all the data from the remote table will be pulled locally so the local database can do the minus.  The query plan will show you which option Oracle has chosen.
